# funky mouse click not working issue Win10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse

So on my work PC I have been having this issue.  My corporate service desk just wants to re-image the PC but in addition to that being a pain, I have to admit I am truly fascinated by the nuance of this issue so I was interested in exploring a little further.  Curious to see if anyone here has run into similar.

This started a few months ago but has seemingly gotten worse in recent weeks.  Basically when I am at my desk and connected to my USB-C dock thing...when I unlock my PC the left (and probably right) mouseclick only works for the application that is on top....  but then usually 15-20 minutes later...the mouse works normally.

During the time of the problem, I can move the mouse all over the screen, and it usually works in that "top" application.  I can even alt-tab around my PC and fully interact with any application without any responsiveness issues...provided I do it with the keyboard (tabbing through menus etc).

If I alt-tab to another application and click with the mouse, the PC registers the click, because windows "deselects" the app when I do.  Its as if there is a transparent overlay app on my computer that is behind anything other than the app that is on top...

Have changed mouse/keyboard and dock (including going from wireless mouse to wired), drivers have been updated.  No problem exists when using touchpad and dont seem to have problem when at home and just using usb wired mouse.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the device's usb drivers and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Does this happen with any app or a specific one?

Comment: Depending on the dock, there is typically firmware updates available deep in the support download section. I have done this in the past for Lenovo, Dell, and MS Surface. Try hunting it down and see if that works. 

This could be a good place to start if you do not see the issue when the mouse is connected directly to the computer, bypassing the dock.